# Let $F$ be a field, and $J =\{f\in F[X,Y] \vert f(0,Y) = 0\}$, $J$ is not maximal

Tags: ring-theory

It's clear to me that $J$ is a principal ideal in $F[X,Y]$ and also that it is not maximal. A given example is: $J \subset (J,Y^2) \subset F[X,Y]$.

My problem lies with the example. I don't see why it should be $(J,Y^2)$ to properly contain $J$. Wouldn't $J \subset (J,Y)$ be also correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's also correct.  There are many different ideals that properly contain $J$; both $(J,Y^2)$ and $(J,Y)$ are examples, as are $(J,y+1)$, $(J, y^7+y+2)$, and many others.  I'm not sure why they chose to give you the example $(J,Y^2)$; there's nothing particularly special about it, and $(J,Y)$ is in some sense the "simplest" example.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I also thought that $(J,Y)$ would be the "simplest" example and assumed there were something wrong with it, since they went with $(J,Y^2)$.